# Docker swarm doesn't see networking from compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am deploying micro services app to swarm. I've already written `docker-compose-prod.yml`, which is working fine when being deployed just though `docker compose up`, but when I run `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose-prod.yml app` services, which must connect to mongo db service are failing because they don't see shared network.

docker-compose-prod.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  redis:
    build: redis/
    image: someimage
    restart: always
    networks:
      - redis
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.4.7-focal
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - mongo/.env
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db
    networks:
      - mongo
        
  token_service:
    build: token_service/
    image: someimage
    command: "-cfg ./config/config_prod.yml"
    networks:
      - backend

  user_service:
    build: user_service/
    image: someimage
    command: "-db_address ${MONGODB_ADDRESS:-mongodb://mongodb:${MONGODB_PORT:-27017}} -port ${USER_SERVICE_PORT:-9385}"
    networks:
      - backend
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  music_service:
    build: music_service/
    image: someimage
    command:
      [
        "-user_service_address",
        "user_service:${USER_SERVICE_PORT:-9385}",
        "-port",
        "${MUSIC_SERVICE_PORT:-7070}",
        "-db_address",
        "${MONGODB_ADDRESS:-27017}"
      ]
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - mongo
      - backend

  photo_service:
    build: photo_service/
    image: someimage
    command:
      [
        "-music_service_address",
        "music_service:${MUSIC_SERVICE_PORT:-7070}",
        "-user_service_address",
        "user_service:${USER_SERVICE_PORT:-9385}",
        "-port",
        "${PHOTO_SERVICE_PORT:-7345}"
      ]
    depends_on:
      - music_service
      - user_service
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - backend

  player_service:
    build: player_service/
    image: someimage
    command:
      [
        "-msaddress",
        "music_service:${MUSIC_SERVICE_PORT:-7070}",
        "-rport",
        "${REDIS_PORT:-6379}",
        "-rhost",
        "redis",
        "-port",
        "${PLAYER_SERVICE_PORT:-6060}"
      ]
    environment:
      - GIN_MODE=release

    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - backend
      - redis

  playlist_service:
    build: playlist_service/
    image: someimage
    command:
      [
        "-msaddress",
        "music_service:${MUSIC_SERVICE_PORT:-7070}",
        "-rport",
        "${REDIS_PORT:-6379}",
        "-rhost",
        "redis",
        "-port",
        "${PLAYLIST_SERVICE_PORT:-6061}",
        "-usaddress",
        "user_service:${USER_SERVICE_PORT:-9385}"
      ]
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - music_service
      - user_service
    networks:
      - backend
      - redis

networks:
  backend:
  mongo:
  redis:


volumes:
  mongodata:
  redisdata:
```

`someimage`'s are obviously different. I've uploaded images to docker-hub, so docker swarm can pull them fluently

`docker stack ps app`:
[image]

music_service logs:

```
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    | INFO  2023/02/11 10:51:49 Trying to connect to database
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    | panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    | [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x86baad]
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    |
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    | goroutine 1 [running]:
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    | go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.newDatabase(0x0, {0xb49e74, 0xf}, {0x0?, 0x37?, 0x37?})
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    |   /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.11.1/mongo/database.go:47 +0xcd
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    | go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.(*Client).Database(...)
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    |   /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.11.1/mongo/client.go:627
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    | music_service/funcs/db.setupConfigVariables()
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    |   /go/src/music_service/funcs/db/db_connection.go:26 +0x11b
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    | music_service/funcs/db.connectToDb()
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    |   /go/src/music_service/funcs/db/db_connection.go:18 +0x19
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    | music_service/funcs/db.ConnectBD()
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    |   /go/src/music_service/funcs/db/db_connection.go:13 +0x54
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    | main.main()
app_music_service.1.jhuxk5kck54x@sw1    |   /go/src/music_service/main.go:11 +0x71
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    | INFO  2023/02/11 10:52:00 Trying to connect to database
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    | panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    | [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x86baad]
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    |
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    | goroutine 1 [running]:
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    | go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.newDatabase(0x0, {0xb49e74, 0xf}, {0x0?, 0x37?, 0x37?})
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    |   /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.11.1/mongo/database.go:47 +0xcd
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    | go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.(*Client).Database(...)
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    |   /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.11.1/mongo/client.go:627
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    | music_service/funcs/db.setupConfigVariables()
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    |   /go/src/music_service/funcs/db/db_connection.go:26 +0x11b
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    | music_service/funcs/db.connectToDb()
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    |   /go/src/music_service/funcs/db/db_connection.go:18 +0x19
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    | music_service/funcs/db.ConnectBD()
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    |   /go/src/music_service/funcs/db/db_connection.go:13 +0x54
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    | main.main()
app_music_service.1.la9olwptv2yi@sw1    |   /go/src/music_service/main.go:11 +0x71
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    | INFO  2023/02/11 10:52:21 Trying to connect to database
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    | panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    | [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x86baad]
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    |
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    | goroutine 1 [running]:
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    | go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.newDatabase(0x0, {0xb49e74, 0xf}, {0x0?, 0x37?, 0x37?})
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    |   /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.11.1/mongo/database.go:47 +0xcd
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    | go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.(*Client).Database(...)
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    |   /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.11.1/mongo/client.go:627
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    | music_service/funcs/db.setupConfigVariables()
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    |   /go/src/music_service/funcs/db/db_connection.go:26 +0x11b
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    | music_service/funcs/db.connectToDb()
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    |   /go/src/music_service/funcs/db/db_connection.go:18 +0x19
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    | music_service/funcs/db.ConnectBD()
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    |   /go/src/music_service/funcs/db/db_connection.go:13 +0x54
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    | main.main()
app_music_service.1.n48kwxkz27be@sw1    |   /go/src/music_service/main.go:11 +0x71
```

user_service logs:

```
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    | INFO   2023/02/11 10:53:31 Trying to connect to database at mongodb://mongodb:${MONGODB_PORT:-27017}
app_user_service.1.025nl14hev72@sw1    |    /go/src/user_service/main.go:11 +0x72
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    | panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    | [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x2d8 pc=0x7c394d]
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    |
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    | goroutine 1 [running]:
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    | go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.newDatabase(0x0, {0xab02b9, 0xf}, {0x0?, 0x63?, 0x70?})
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    |    /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.3.1/mongo/database.go:46 +0xcd
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    | go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.(*Client).Database(...)
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    |    /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.3.1/mongo/client.go:655
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    | user_service/funcs/db.setupConfigVariables()
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    |    /go/src/user_service/funcs/db/db_funcs.go:27 +0x10c
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    | user_service/funcs/db.connectToDb()
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    |    /go/src/user_service/funcs/db/db_funcs.go:18 +0x6c
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    | user_service/funcs/db.ConnectBD(...)
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    |    /go/src/user_service/funcs/db/db_funcs.go:13
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    | INFO   2023/02/11 10:52:58 Trying to connect to database at mongodb://mongodb:${MONGODB_PORT:-27017}
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    | panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    | [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x2d8 pc=0x7c394d]
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    |
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    | goroutine 1 [running]:
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    | go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.newDatabase(0x0, {0xab02b9, 0xf}, {0x0?, 0x63?, 0x70?})
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    |    /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.3.1/mongo/database.go:46 +0xcd
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    | main.main()
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    | go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.(*Client).Database(...)
app_user_service.1.rb076726mnl6@sw1    |    /go/src/user_service/main.go:11 +0x72
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    |    /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.3.1/mongo/client.go:655
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    | user_service/funcs/db.setupConfigVariables()
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    |    /go/src/user_service/funcs/db/db_funcs.go:27 +0x10c
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    | user_service/funcs/db.connectToDb()
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    |    /go/src/user_service/funcs/db/db_funcs.go:18 +0x6c
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    | user_service/funcs/db.ConnectBD(...)
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    |    /go/src/user_service/funcs/db/db_funcs.go:13
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    | main.main()
app_user_service.1.mobmprrfs68e@sw1    |    /go/src/user_service/main.go:11 +0x72
```

From user_service's and music_service's logs we can see, that the problem is in the connection to mongodb

**Question**

In `user_service` logs I've noticed, that my environments are not working as I suggested. As in the first question it is working fine if not in swarm. How to fix it?

Comment: docker compose up will create bridge networks by default which are local to specific hosts, docker stack deploy will create overlay networks - which is a software defined network that spans nodes. You might need to just explicitly specify the network type as overlay.

Comment: Do your services wait for mongo to start?